# What data type would have a structure with a maximum size and elements are FIFO?

Tags: c++, arrays, data-structures, queue, c++03

I want to store some values, but only store three at a time. If a fourth were to be stored, the oldest value in the structure would be removed to make room.

For example:

```cpp
const unsigned int BUFFER = 3; // maximum size
SomeType s(BUFFER);
s.add(1); // s is now 1 --> NULL --> NULL
s.add(3); // s is now 3 --> 1 --> NULL
s.add(6); // s is now 6 --> 3 --> 1
s.add(4); // s is now 4 --> 6 --> 3 (1 was removed)
```

Is there a built-in data structure in C++03 or am I required to make my own?

Comment: [boost::circular_buffer](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/doc/html/circular_buffer.html)? There is nothing like that in the standard library.

Comment: A circular buffer? It's not in the standard library though.

Comment: You want a circular queue, I believe. Afaik, this is not part of the STL, but is relatively simple to implement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a built in data structure in C++03

A data structure that would be appropriate for what you describe is circular buffer.

There is no such container in the standard library.

> or am I required to make my own?

You can make your own. A circular buffer can be implemented on top of a sequence container. Or - as always - you can use a pre-existing library.

Answer (score 2):

As far as built-in structures for C++, you could use [`std::queue`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/queue/queue/), though you will need to include a check for size yourself as there isn't a built in way to limit it to 3.

This would be pretty simple though if you simply check the size of the queue as you are pushing an item into the FIFO queue. If the queue is already at `size==3` you call the `pop` function to remove the element at the top of the list and then `push` the new element into the queue.

Comment: This. I would highly recommend creating his own queue class if it were to be used many times.